# Drag position issue with event touch move on touch screen

Tags: javascript, css

I have implemented drag and drop with html/JavaScript. It works well with mouse drag but having issue with touch screen. while dragging item on touch screen it's position is not correct either it goes up or down from the touch point. Thanks in advance!

```
var _left = _touch.clientX;
var _top = _touch.clientY;
_touch.target.style.left = _left + 'px';
_touch.target.style.top = _top + 'px';
```

Comment: Could you make a working snippet so we can try for outselves. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue has been resolved. The fix is as below:

```
var droppable = document.elementFromPoint(_touch.clientX, _touch.clientY);
var _left = _touch.clientX - droppable.getBoundingClientRect().left;
var _top = _touch.clientY - droppable.getBoundingClientRect().top;
_touch.target.style.left = _left + 'px';
_touch.target.style.top = _top + 'px';
```

I am getting the droppable container's left and top and subtracting it from draggable item.